# Repeating jobs of sequential file names

Tags: command

If I have `sample_1.txt`, `sample_2.txt`, `sample_3.txt`, `sample_4.txt`, and I want to perform a command line job repeatedly.

For example, instead of typing the same command four times like below, is there a command that could do that automatically?

```
$ grep 'pattern' sample_1.txt
$ grep 'pattern' sample_2.txt
$ grep 'pattern' sample_3.txt
$ grep 'pattern' sample_4.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$grep 'pattern' sample_1.txt sample_2.txt sample_3.txt sample_4.txt
```

And also can use simple bash script for command which not accept multipe input>>

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( ls ); do
        grep "include" $i
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But 'grep' was just an example. The program I have to run cannot accept multiple files as input.

Comment: I have change the code watch it could be use full to you?